# How do I remove elements from a jQuery selection or cloned html?

Tags: jquery, css, find, clone

I'm building a jQuery mini-plugin to show a print preview and then print the results of some reports that my application runs.  I need the ability to not print certain sections (for example: reports that have no results, UI elements, etc).  I've tried the css @media print to no avail.  I don't know why it doesn't work, but I've implemented it exactly as described on the w3schools media types page and IE still wants to print those elements.

So I've decided to brute force it and just remove the .noPrint elements from a cloned DOM.  As it turns out, this will solve a problem I was looking forward to having with my planned "output to .pdf" functionality.

My problem is that while

```
    $(clonedHtml).find('.noPrint')
```

returns a collection of the noPrint elements quite nicely,

```
    $(clonedHtml).remove('.noPrint')
```

doesn't remove anything.  I've also tried removing it like this:

```
    var removeMe = $(clonedHtml).find('.noPrint');
    clonedHtml.remove(removeMe);
```

Which obviously doesn't work either.  This syntax is based off the API documentation's second example:

```
    $("p").remove(":contains('Hello')");
    Removes all paragraphs that contain "Hello" from the DOM. Analogous to doing 
    $("p").filter(":contains('Hello')").remove().
```

The real question: Why?  I checked the API documentation for remove(), I've read everything I could find on google, and I've searched the jQuery forums and can't find anything.

Comment: first place to read before google and forums, is api specification http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: i did not vote you down, because the question was well formulated; in my comment i just wanted you to note that the time for asking in here was probably enough to have a second read through the documentation

Comment: Okay.  Deleted my comment.  Apologies for my assumption.  But yeah, that was the first place I looked.  Updated my question to reflect that fact, hopefully to help anyone who searches for this in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: ok; are you implying that the documentation is wrong in your edit? because the api docs are just right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(clonedHtml).find('.noPrint').remove();
```

Comment: AHHHHH!  Thank you!  I'm an idiot--that exact line is commented out in my huge list of test lines, except I was using the actual document rather than the clone.  It got lost in the deluge of experimentation I've been doing.  I'll accept in about 8 minutes.  That said...any idea why $(clonedHtml).remove('.noPrint'); doesn't work?

Comment: @Will: You are welcome :) It didn't work because you had wrong syntax for remove method.